# Get list of SHIR from cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We create multiple SHIR’s in our organization for different purposes. I would like to know, how to get list of all SHIR’s created by X user. E.g., I want to get list of all Self Hosted IR’s created by me from Azure cloud shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct command, but you can try below command to get list of IR’s created by particular User.

When creating Self hosted IR, add the name of user in description. Then find the list of SHIR’s from Azure cloud shell using below command

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName ******** -DataFactoryName ********* | where Description -eq "User_name"| Select name
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2integrationruntime?view=azps-8.0.0#description) for more information